# Modifying products per row

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, catalog

I have seen previous questions relating to this but none have helped so far. My store currently displays 3 products per row and a sidebar and I want to change that to four without the sidebar.

I changed the page layout to 1 column within admin, which removed the sidebar but I can't get the grid to display 4 products.

I've tried modifying **catalog.xml** by adding the  `<action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>` within both `product_list` nodes and then clearing cache but nothing changed.

The HTML is outputting:

```
<ul class="products-grid">
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="products-grid">
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
</ul>
```

How can I change this to four? If changing the **catalog.xml** doesn't work what may that suggest? We were given this store by other developers, so I'm not sure if something is being overriden.

Comment: Make sure you are editing correct layout update handle and catalog.xml

Answer (score 2):

There are three places in catalog.xml you will find setColumnCount; Catalog Category (Non-Anchor), Catalog Category (Anchor), and Catalog Product View (Any). Make sure that you are changing the right one.

If that doesn't work and are using some kind of module for category sorting, it can override the column count in the catalog.xml

Also, make sure you are editing your files in your theme's directory!